# How to Restore GRUB after installing Windows?

Tags: boot, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Hi installed W7 after Ubuntu 11.04, and it broke up my boot options, I followed this tutorial to restore boot loader: [Recovering Ubuntu After Installing Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).
But when i run:

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/media/5292fba2-f517-466d-a120-b8a61a97ca8a/boot /dev/sda2
```

I get this errors:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Attempting to install GRUB to a partitionless disk or to a partition.  This is a BAD idea..
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

Can somebody help me with this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guide do not say to use `/dev/sda2`: it is a partition.

You should install GRUB to the disk boot sector, I suppose in your case is `/dev/sda`.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there are good reasons to install GRUB2 into a partition, not into the disk's MBR, e.g. when you have multiple operating systems on the disk.  The 11.10 Kubuntu installer did install grub2 into a partition without problems, and I could boot-chain into it from the bootloader installed in the MBR.  But when moving partitions around, one has to manually use grub-install.

The command is then:

```
sudo grub-install --force /dev/sda6
```

Comment: Had a dual boot on iMac with refit pointing to ubuntu partition, and need to install grub directly there. this did the trick!